# automatization of requests

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, rest, python-requests

I need to carve out JSON-file from web interface for a certain time period. Notes' limit - 100. JSON-file consists from some events and timestamps, when events happened. If the response is too big, I get the notification in file - moreDataAvailable = True. To get other data which are not included in file that I already got, I need to make a new request with some changes in URL - to change the timestamp on timestamp of last event (receivedDateTime) increased it by 1 millisecond.

So, I've already wrote the request via Python with requests.get()

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get(
...     'https://api.blablabla.com/event/eventstatuses?requestId=1234&datetype=received&starttime=2020-02-10T00%3A00%3A57.001Z&...'
... )
>>> json_response = response.json()
>>> print(json_response)
```

How I can to automatize my requests to carve out all data in requested period? (moreDataAvailable = False)
Is it possible to connect all downloaded JSONs, for example, in a one file to export it in a data warehouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write a loop for this.

```
import time
timeout = time.time() + 60*5   # 5 minutes from now
while True:
    sendRequest()
    if time.time() > timeout:
        break
    time.sleep(60)   # Delays for 60 seconds. You can also use a float value.


def sendRequest():
  import requests
  response = requests.get(
    'https://api.blablabla.com/event/eventstatuses? 
      requestId=1234&datetype=received&starttime=2020-02- 
       10T00%3A00%3A57.001Z&...'
   )
  json_response = response.json()
  print(json_response)
```